# DOMTokenList v .classList

Tags: javascript, html, domtokenlist

In HTML (or javascript or whatever), is there a different between `DOMTokenList` and what is returned from `Element.classList`?  On [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList), browser compatibility of `Element.classList` is listed differently than for `DOMTokenList`.   Is this sloppiness on MDN's part or is there really a difference in compatibility between the two or is it that nobody cares about the other uses of `DOMTokenList`?

Comment: Since `classList` is a subset of all properties that return a `DOMTokenList` and the MDN support information for `classList` claims browsers supporting `classList` are a subset of browsers supporting `DOMTokenList` … I don't understand where your confusion comes from.

Comment: @Quentn MDN lists `DOMTokenList` as single-arg (or at least is silent about multi-arg), while `classList` explicitly listed as multi-arg.  This implies `classList` is not subset but rather a superset of `DOMTokenList`.   I don't know if `classList` is an augmented version of `DOMTokenList`.   Now, in practice, on latest Chrome and Firefox, I find DOMTokenList to be multi-arg capable, but I don't know if that is standard or not or how backwards compatible this is.

Comment: What do you mean by "single-arg" and "multi-arg"? I can't find the terms on the relevant pages. Can you quote the sections of the MDN documentation that you are asking about?